# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 415 - how to get the double quotes parsed in JSON using json.loads in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string, double-quotes

I have wrote a code like below -

```
>>> text = "ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ \"АПК\" \"РАССВЕТ\""
>>> text = text.replace('"', '\"').replace("'", "\'")
>>> data = '{"text": "' + str(text) + '"}'
>>> print(data)
{"text": "ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ "АПК" "РАССВЕТ""}
>>> final_data = json.loads(data)
```

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 53 (char 52)

Do we have any other way to make the double quotes parsed in json.loads ? Help me out please.

Comment: Why are you creating JSON manually in the first place? Populate the appropriate data structure, and then encode that as JSON.

Comment: Try `json.dumps({'text':text})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can write your JSON object and then use `json.dumps()` to get the string, but if you really want to manually write the JSON as a string and then load it with `json.loads()`:

```
data = """{ "text": "%s" }""" % text.replace('\"', '\\"').replace("'", "\\'")
json.loads(data)  # {'text': 'ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ "АПК" "РАССВЕТ"'}
```

With `json.dumps()`:

```
json.dumps({"text": text}, ensure_ascii=False)
# '{"text": "ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ \\"АПК\\" \\"РАССВЕТ\\""}'
```

Comment: If we have a list - text = ['ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ "АПК" "РАССВЕТ"', 'LIMITED LIABILITY COMPANY "APK" "RASSVET"'] , how to parse this using json.loads ?https://stackoverflow.com/users/6273711/user

Comment: If I answered your question, please consider accepting my answer. As for your doubt, the string now would simply be the first element of `text`, ie: `json_loads(text[0])`